# Cannot execute macro in Break Mode

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to write a simple macro to add 1 to the cell's current value:

```
Sub add()
    MsgBox Selection.Value
    Selection.Value = Selection.Value + 1
End Sub
```

I receive the following error message when I click a (numeric) cell and try to run the macro:

```
Cannot Execute in Break Mode
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `Selecdtion.Value + 1` - there's a typo here, by the way

Comment: You should always have Option Explicit at the top of your code modules. That would have told you that "Selecdtion.Value" is not valid. Once you've fixed that, see how you go.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are already executing a macro and somehow stopped its execution (e.g. due to an unhandled error or because you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd> during the execution). In this state, you cannot execute another macro.

In the Visual Basic Editor, you need to press the Stop button:
[image]

Then you can run the macro.

If you want to understand where the current execution is stopped, right click the code and select *Show Next Statement*. If you then press <kbd>F8</kbd> you can step through the code. <kbd>F5</kbd> continues the execution.

Comment: + 1 nicely explained as usual :)

Comment: Thanks very much, new to debugging in VBA, was very confused

Answer (score 1):

And you should check if the value in the cell is numeric. Example

```
Sub add()
    If IsNumeric(Selection.Value) Then
        Selection.Value = Selection.Value + 1
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not a value selected")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Sub Lower()
    Range ("e3"), Value = Range("e3"), Value - 1
End Sub

Sub Higher()
    Range ("e3"), Value = Range("e3"), Value + 1
End Sub
```