# Executing VBA code through button

Tags: vba, excel

I want to assign the below VBA code to a button. This is what I did:

1.Clicked on Developer option and and "Insert"
  2. Insert->Form control->Button.
  3. When it prompted me to select a macro, I selected my code..which is WBR.
  4. But when I click on it, it doesn't execute (no error is thrown up as well)

I'm not sure what is causing the problem.

My code is pretty huge so just giving the sample:

```
Sub WBR()

Dim Count1Criteria As Variant
Dim Count3Criteria As Variant
Dim test As Variant
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction



Filter1InSummary = Array(Array("AH4", "Latency", "Pass/Fail", "Pass"), _
                         Array("AH5", "Latency", "Pass/Fail", "Fail"), _
                         Array("AH44", "TT", "Able to repro", "Not Tested"), _
                         Array("AH47", "TT", "Reason for Reasssignment/Resolving", "Duplicate TT"), _
                         Array("AH51", "TT", "Able to repro", "Yes"), _
                         Array("AH52", "TT", "Able to repro", "No"), _
                         Array("AH61", "Reactive", "Item Type", "Item"), _
                         Array("AH46", "TT", "Reason for Reasssignment/Resolving", "Hardware Unavailable"), _
                         Array("AH41", "TT", "Severity", "2"), _
                         Array("AH62", "Reactive", "Trigger Key Name", "*App Crashes*"), _
                         Array("AH63", "Reactive", "Trigger Key Name", "*Download*"), _
                         Array("AH49", "TT", "Reason for Reasssignment/Resolving", "Insufficient Information"), _
                         Array("AH15", "Latency", "Comments", "*Waived since unable to repro issue*"), _
                         Array("AH16", "Latency", "Comments", "*Waived due to business reasons*"), _
                         Array("AH18", "Non-Mhowls", "Type of testing", "Full Testing"), _
                         Array("AH19", "Non-Mhowls", "Type of testing", "Upgrade Testing"))




 For Each test In Filter1InSummary
    With Worksheets(test(1))
        Range(test(0)) = wf.CountIfs(.Rows(1).Find(test(2), lookat:=xlWhole).EntireColumn, test(3))
    End With
    Next
```

Comment: Put Break Point on line `Sub WBR()`, then click button, then step over line by line to see what is happening.

Comment: I'm sorry...Im new to VBA and I'm not sure what you are referring to..can you please explain in a way I can understand?

Comment: In Visual Basic Editor (VBE), select the module that contains the `Sub WBR()`. Then click somewhere inside the first line, and press F9 key, that is set break point (indicated by a dot on left side, and line highlighted). After that, when you press the button in the worksheet, it should open the VBE with the first line highlighted. Then keep pressing F8 (step into)... Also, please explain what are you trying to do with the macro, maybe someone will come up with simpler solution.

Comment: where do you expect to see the `CountIfs` results?

Comment: In WBR45 sheet @user3598756

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot execute in break mode" message @Branislav Kollár

Comment: try placing a `MsgBox test(0) & " - " & test(1) & " - " & test(2)` statement right after `For Each test In Filter1InSummary` and see if the outcome from message boxes is the expected one

Comment: Maybe you are running different code at the same time, see [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14934595/4636801). Consider hitting the "Stop" button.

Comment: Hi Walter. did you try first to run your macro from the VB editor directly? To do so, just place the cursor inside the sub and press `F5`, or alternatively, press `F8` to execute it step by step.

Comment: Yes I did that. The code works perfectly fine when I press F5

Comment: I just have a doubt..My code (pasted above) doesn't say where these results should be paste ..right? 'Cos I want the results in "WBR" sheet. Is that why the when I pass control trough the button the code doesn't know where to give the results?